# Android Studio 3.0 Library Error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

My project is worked fine but today I have some error about build.gradle file.I searched in google but I didn't find any solution.How can I solve this error?

[error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6BQV.png)

and this is project build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}}
```

and Allprojects

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
} }
```

Comment: add your app level and project level gradle files in question

Comment: compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.I am getting the error,because that there is no such a library in repository.I read to documentation this link **Support Library Package**. I removed the error-giving libraries and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect your device (in which you are running android studio) to the internet.90% of the problem is due to the internet connection and if it is not solving your problem try to open logcat and copy that red thing and show me.
If that solved your problem then approved my answer.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I got a this error in logcat         
Error:Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:26.3.1.
  Searched in the following locations:
      file:/C:/Users/Adige-Enes/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.3.1/support-v4-26.3.1.pom

Answer (score 0):

The support libraries are now available through Google's Maven repository.

Step 1: Open the build.gradle file of your project.

Step 2: Make sure that the repositories section includes a maven section with the "https://maven.google.com" url in it.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeap I know maven repositories already exist in my projects and I tried to SDK manager uninstall and install but I have same error

Comment: I mentioned check it.

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'

Comment: If I changed this way compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0''' I got new error about this section 
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.

Answer (score 0):

- in Android Studio, open Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager
- under tab "SDK Tools" un-check the libraries causing problems
  click "apply" to uninstall them
- re-check the same libraries
  click "apply" to reinstall them
  close SDK Manager and run Gradle sync / build